# function call inside another function with using javascript Global variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

Following java script is not working global variable pls help to do. Ajax is working properly and in add_article() function also working as variable but the variable not working undefined.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var karat = 0;
function get_advance_amount(element)
{
    if (element!="")
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            key = new XMLHttpRequest();
            key.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (key.status==200 && key.readyState ==4) 
                {
                karat = key.responseText;
                //alert(karat); // this is working
                }

            };
            key.open("GET","get_advance_amount.php?q="+element,true);
            key.send();
        }
    }
}
function add_article()
{
    get_advance_amount('2');
    alert(karat); // this is not working
}
</script>
<button onclick="add_article()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. So, the alert after the `get_advance_amount('2');`.
You need to add it inside the `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: The *A* in *Ajax* stands for **asynchronous**.

Comment: how to do please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add_article function runs before the XHR's done.

Sample rewrite:

```
'use strict'

function getAdvanceAmount (element, callback) {
  if (element === '' || !window.XMLHttpRequest) return

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) {
      callback(xhr.responseText)
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', 'get_advance_amount.php?q=' + element, true)
  xhr.send()
}

function addArticle () {
  getAdvanceAmount('2', function (karat) {
    console.log(karat)
  })
}
```

This technique is used as callbacks, where you supply a function that gets called and provided with data once the async operation's done. Here, `getAdvanceAmount()` accepts a callback which will be run once the XHR's completed. `addArticle()` could also take a callback if it's necessary to know when it's done.

Newer ways to do this are [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) and the proposal for [async/await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) (which actually uses promises behind the scenes). For example, promises would be used like this:

```
function addArticle () {
  getAdvanceAmount('2').then(karat => console.log(karat))
}
```

and async/await like this:

```
async function addArticle () {
  const karat = await getAdvanceAmount('2')
  console.log(karat)
}
```

However, use of these in a browser environment requires polyfilling and transpiling.

Comment: You might want to provide an explanation for your solution.

Comment: this code is not working

Comment: @DerickChooty Which one isn't working?

Comment: i try that you gave code but no result

Comment: @DerickChooty It should work now.

Comment: Have you tried running my whole script not just part of it?

Comment: thank Felix Kiling thanks a lot grate job. its working